# How to pass a dataGrid's columns as parameters in wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a DataGrid which ItemsSource is `List<string>`.
Second column is ComboBox which is also bound to a `List<string>`, but another.

When user hits click button I want to see in my command function two parameters to be passed: Green and red. So, how to do that?

[image]

So in my button column I want to see smth like:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn>
  <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
       <Button Content="click"
         Command="{Binding DataContext.ListenCmd, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}" 
         Margin="5,5">
         <Button.CommandParameter>
            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource MultiConverter}">
              <Binding Path="--First Column Value--"/>
              <Binding Path="--Second Column Value--"/>
             </MultiBinding>
        </Button.CommandParameter>
      </Button>
     </DataTemplate>
  </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Multibining as:

```
<MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource MultiConverter}">
   <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGridCellsPanel}}" Path="Children[0].Content.Text"/>
    <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGridCellsPanel}}" Path="Children[1].Content.Text"/>
</MultiBinding>
```

I Hope you have a logic in `MultiConverter` to encapsulate both values into one `object`.

> ***Above binding can cause problem if you are using any complex `DataGridCell` `Template`.***